# Finding a polynomial $P\in\Bbb R[x]$ such that $|\sqrt[3]x-P(x)|\le\frac1{100}, \forall x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

A very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846340/find-taylor-series-polynomial-that-gives-uniform-bound-on-error) has already been asked before, but here the cubic root appears:

> Find a polynomial $P\in\Bbb R[x]$ such that $|\sqrt[3]x-P(x)|\le\frac1{100},\forall x\in[0,1]$

From what I understand, $P$ should be a Taylor polynomial $T_n$ (which, I know, is the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ partial sum of the corresponding Taylor series) around $c\in[0,1]$ of the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ of a suitable degree and $\sqrt[3]x-P(x)=R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c_x)}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{n+1}$ for some $c_x$ between $c$ and $x$.
Since there is $1/3$ in the exponent, I didn't try applying the Stirling's approximation. Instead, I have the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt[3]x$ around $x=1$:

$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt[3]x&=\sqrt[3]{1+(x-1)}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/3}n(x-1)^n\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\frac13\left(\frac13-1\right)\left(\frac13-2\right)\cdots\left(\frac13-(n-1)\right)}{3^nn!}(x-1)^n\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(3n-4)!!!}{(3n)!!!}(x-1)^n,\end{aligned}$$

however, I'm not sure how to proceed.
I also considered Lagrange interpolation polynomial, but $\sqrt[3] x$ has an infinite slope at $x=0$.

I also tried using the hint from the thread, which is, the Taylor series of $\sqrt[3]{x+\varepsilon}$ around $x=1:$
$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt[3]{x+\varepsilon}&=\sqrt[3]{x-1+\varepsilon+1}\\&=\sqrt[3]{1+\varepsilon}\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{x-1}{1+\varepsilon}}\\&=\sqrt[3]{1+\varepsilon}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(3n-4)!!!}{(3n)!!!(1+\varepsilon)^n}(x-1)^n.\end{aligned}$$

I believe I'm either missing something or that I made a mistake. What is step should I take next? How to find the large enough $\deg(P)=n$ so that the approximation is correct up two $2$ decimal digits?

---

**EDIT:**

As advised in the comments, I developed $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ around $c=\frac12$:

$\begin{aligned}\sqrt[3]x&=\left(\frac12+\left(x-\frac12\right)\right)^\frac13\\&=\frac1{2^3}\left(1+2\left(x-\frac12\right)\right)^\frac13\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/3}n2^{n-1/3}\left(x-\frac12\right)^n,\end{aligned}$

but I'm still a bit confused as to how to determine which is the least degree of the Taylor polynomial that suits us.

---

Thank you very much!

Comment: The inequality $|\sqrt[3]{x}-P(x)|\leqslant\frac{1}{100}$ should be valid for which $x$ ? I guess it is for all $x\in[0,1]$...

Comment: @Tuvasbien, my apology!

Comment: Wouldn't centering at 0 be a bit simpler?  Or if you wanted to go for a minimum degree polynomial,  center somewhere in between, like $\frac 1 2$

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{x}$ isn't differentiable at $x = 0$, so we can't form a Taylor series there. But yes, centering at a point in between $0$ and $1$ should be a better.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, I got the following after expanding: $$\begin{aligned}\sqrt[3]x&=\left(\frac12+\left(x-\frac12\right)\right)^\frac13\\&=\frac1{2^3}\left(1+2\left(x-\frac12\right)\right)^\frac13\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/3}n2^{n-1/3}\left(x-\frac12\right)^n,\end{aligned}$$ but I don't know how to find $n$ so that the error is less than $0.01$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

Use the Binomial theorem for ($x=1+x-1$) and $a=\frac{1}{3}$:

$$x^{a-1}=f(x)$$

At the end you get someting like $$x\left(1 + a (x - 1) + \frac{1}{2} (a - 1) a (x - 1)^2 + \frac{1}{6} (a - 2) (a - 1) a (x - 1)^3 + \frac{1}{24} (a - 3) (a - 2) (a - 1) a (x - 1)^4 + \frac{1}{120} (a - 4) (a - 3) (a - 2) (a - 1) a (x - 1)^5 \cdots\right)$$

With an equality at $x=0$ and $x=1$

Comment: Isn't it the expansion of $x^a$ around $1$ in the parentheses?

Comment: @Dolphin yes why ?

Comment: It seems I missunderstood something. I thought, from your hint, that we develop $x^{a-1}$ around $1$ and then multiply by $x$ the series obtained.

Comment: @Dolphin Yes that's the trick !